# How do I create a mock function in Rust?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, compiler-errors, scope, closures

I'm trying to run unit tests on a function  `reducer` .  `reducer`  takes in a struct  `State`  and an enum  `Action`  and returns a new struct  `State` . When the action is  `Action::Status` , I want the function state.status_function to be called on state. I'm having trouble testing that a mock function I pass into  `test_status`  is called with state. Does anyone know what I'm getting wrong in the code below?

```rust
fn test_status() {
    let mut status_mock_called: bool;
    let state = State {
        status_function: Box::new(|state: State| {
             status_mock_called = true;
             return state;
        }),
     };
     assert_eq!(root_reducer(state, Action::Status), state);
     assert!(status_mock_called);
}
```

Outputs the error:

```
`(dyn std::ops::Fn(State) -> State + 'static)` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
```

**How can I modify a rust variable from inside a function?**
Here is the state struct in case it's relevant:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
struct State {
    status_function: Box<dyn Fn(State) -> State>,
}
```

And here is the reducer:

```rust
fn root_reducer(state: State, action: Action) -> State {
    match action {
        Action::Status => (state.status_function)(state),
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a [closure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html) instead.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Can you edit your question and clarify what you'd like your function named `a` to actually do? Then we can describe a suitable way to do it using Rust.

Comment: @Bobulous So basically this was a simplified version of my way more complex question, so I will try the more complex version and see if anyone understands