# Unit testing, mocking and traits in rust

Tags: unit-testing, rust, mocking, tdd, traits

Iam current building a application which heavy relies on File IO, so obviously lots of parts of my code have `File::open(file)`.

Doing some integration tests are ok, I can easily set folders to load file and scenarios needed for it.

The problem comes whatever I want to unit tests, and code branches. I know there is lots of mocking libraries out there that claim to mocks, but i feel my biggest problem is code design itself.

Let's say for instance, I would do the same code in any object oriented language (java in the example), i could write some interfaces, and on tests simple override the default behavior I want to mock, set the a fake `ClientRepository`, whatever reimplemented wih a fixed return, or use some mocking framework, like mockito.

```java
public interface ClientRepository {
   Client getClient(int id)
}

public class ClientRepositoryDB {
   
  private ClientRepository repository;
  
  //getters and setters

  public Client getClientById(int id) {
    Client client = repository.getClient(id);

    //Some data manipulation and validation
  }
}
```

But i couldn`t manage to get the same results in rust, since we endup mixing data with behavior.

On the [RefCell documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.33.0/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html#a-use-case-for-interior-mutability-mock-objects), there is a similar example with the one I gave on java. Some of answers points to traits, [clojures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61941650/how-do-i-create-a-mock-function-in-rust), [conditional compiliation](https://klau.si/blog/mocking-in-rust-with-conditional-compilation/)

We might come with some scenarios in test, first one a public function in some mod.rs

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct SomeData {
    pub name: Option<String>,
    pub address: Option<String>,
}


pub fn get_some_data(file_path: PathBuf) -> Option<SomeData> {
    let mut contents = String::new();


    match File::open(file_path) {
        Ok(mut file) => {
            match file.read_to_string(&mut contents) {
                Ok(result) => result,
                Err(_err) => panic!(
                    panic!("Problem reading file")
                ),
            };
        }
        Err(err) => panic!("File not find"),
    }
    
    // using serde for operate on data output
    let some_data: SomeData = match serde_json::from_str(&contents) {
        Ok(some_data) => some_data,
        Err(err) => panic!(
            "An error occour when parsing: {:?}",
            err
        ),
    };

    //we might do some checks or whatever here
    Some(some_data) or None
}


mod test {

    use super::*;
    
    #[test]
    fn test_if_scenario_a_happen() -> std::io::Result<()> {
       //tied with File::open
       let some_data = get_some_data(PathBuf::new);

        assert!(result.is_some());

        Ok(())
    }


    #[test]
    fn test_if_scenario_b_happen() -> std::io::Result<()> {
       //We might need to write two files, and we want to test is the logic, not the file loading itself
       let some_data = get_some_data(PathBuf::new);

        assert!(result.is_none());

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

The second the same function becoming a trait and some struct implement it.

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct SomeData {
   pub name: Option<String>,
   pub address: Option<String>,
}

trait GetSomeData {
   fn get_some_data(&self, file_path: PathBuf) -> Option<SomeData>;
}

pub struct SomeDataService {}

impl GetSomeData for SomeDataService {
   fn get_some_data(&self, file_path: PathBuf) -> Option<SomeData> {
       let mut contents = String::new();

       match File::open(file_path) {
           Ok(mut file) => {
               match file.read_to_string(&mut contents) {
                   Ok(result) => result,
                   Err(_err) => panic!("Problem reading file"),
               };
           }
           Err(err) => panic!("File not find"),
       }
       // using serde for operate on data output
       let some_data: SomeData = match serde_json::from_str(&contents) {
           Ok(some_data) => some_data,
           Err(err) => panic!("An error occour when parsing: {:?}", err),
       };

       //we might do some checks or whatever here
       Some(some_data) or None
   }
}

impl SomeDataService {
   pub fn do_something_with_data(&self) -> Option<SomeData> {

       self.get_some_data(PathBuf::new())
   }
}


mod test {

   use super::*;
   
   #[test]
   fn test_if_scenario_a_happen() -> std::io::Result<()> {
      //tied with File::open
      let service = SomeDataService{}

      let some_data = service.do_something_with_data(PathBuf::new);

       assert!(result.is_some());

       Ok(())
   }

}
```

On both examples, we have a hard time unit testing it, since we tied with `File::open`, and surely, this might be extend to any non-deterministic function, like time, db connection, etc.

How would you design this or any similar code to make easier to unit testing and better design?

Answer (score 9):

> How would you design this or any similar code to make easier to unit testing and better design?

One way is to make `get_some_data()` generic over the input stream. The `std::io` module defines a `Read` trait for all things you can read from, so it could look like this (untested):

```rust
use std::io::Read;

pub fn get_some_data(mut input: impl Read) -> Option<SomeData> {
    let mut contents = String::new();
    input.read_to_string(&mut contents).unwrap();
    ...
}
```

You'd call `get_some_data()` with the input, e.g. `get_some_data(File::open(file_name).unwrap())` or `get_some_data(&mut io::stdin::lock())`, etc. When testing, you can prepare the input in a string and call it as `get_some_data(io::Cursor::new(prepared_data))`.

As for the trait example, I think you misunderstood how to apply the pattern to your code. You're supposed to use the trait to decouple getting the data from processing the data, sort of how you'd use an interface in Java. The `get_some_data()` function would receive an object known to implement the trait.

Code more similar to what you'd find in an OO language might choose to use [a trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html):

```rust
trait ProvideData {
    fn get_data(&self) -> String
}

struct FileData(PathBuf);

impl ProvideData for FileData {
    fn get_data(&self) -> String {
        std::fs::read(self.0).unwrap()
    }
}

pub fn get_some_data(data_provider: &dyn ProvideData) -> Option<SomeData> {
    let contents = data_provider.get_data();
    ...
}

// normal invocation:
// let some_data = get_some_data(&FileData("file name".into()));
```

In test you'd just create a different implementation of the trait - for example:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    struct StaticData(&'static str);

    impl ProvideData for StaticData {
        fn get_data(&self) -> String {
            self.0.to_string()
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_something() {
        let some_data = get_some_data(StaticData("foo bar"));
        assert!(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

First of all, I would like to thank @user4815162342 for enlightenment of traits. Using his answer as base, i solve with my own solution for the problem.

First, I build as mention, traits to better design my code:

```rust
trait ProvideData {
    fn get_data(&self) -> String
}
```

But I had some problems, since there were tons of bad design code, and lots code I had to mock before run the test, something like the below code.

```rust
pub fn some_function() -> Result<()> {
   let some_data1 = some_non_deterministic_function(PathBuf::new())?;

   let some_data2 = some_non_deterministic_function_2(some_data1);

   match some_data2 {
      Ok(ok) => Ok(()),
      Err(err) => panic!("something went wrong"),
   }
}
```

I would need to change almost all functions signatures to accept `Fn`, this would not only change most my code, but will actually make it hard to read, since most of it I was changing for testing purpose only.

```rust
pub fn some_function(func1: Box<dyn ProvideData>, func2: Box<dyn SomeOtherFunction>) -> Result<()> {
   let some_data1 = func1(PathBuf::new())?;

   let some_data2 = func2(some_data1);

   match some_data2 {
      Ok(ok) => Ok(()),
      Err(err) => panic!("something went wrong"),
   }
}
```

Reading a little more deep the rust documentation, I slight changed the implementation.

1. Change almost all my code to use traits and structs ( Lots of code were public functions )

```rust
trait ProvideData {
    fn get_data(&self) -> String;
}

struct FileData(PathBuf);

impl ProvideData for FileData {
    fn get_data(&self) -> String {
        String::from(format!("Pretend there is something going on here with file {}", self.0.to_path_buf().display()))
    }
}
```

2. Add a `new` functions for default implementation in the structs, and add constructor with default implementation using dynamic dispatch functions.

```rust
struct SomeData(Box<dyn ProvideData>);

impl SomeData {
    pub fn new() -> SomeData {
        let file_data = FileData(PathBuf::new());

        SomeData {
            0: Box::new(file_data)
        }
    }

    pub fn get_some_data(&self) -> Option<String> {
        let contents = self.0.get_data();
        
        Some(contents)
    }
}
```

3. Since the constructor is private, we prevent user from injecting code, and we can freely change the internal implementation for testing purpose, and the integration tests keep running smooth.

```
fn main() {
    //When the user call this function, it would no know that there is multiple implementations for it.

    let some_data = SomeData::new();
    
    assert_eq!(Some(String::from("Pretend there is something going on here with file ")),some_data.get_some_data());
    
    println!("HEY WE CHANGE THE INJECT WITHOUT USER INTERATION");
}
```

And finally, since we test inside the declaration scope, we might change the injection even if is private:

```rust
mod test {
    use super::*;

    struct MockProvider();

    impl ProvideData for MockProvider {
        fn get_data(&self) -> String {
            String::from("Mocked data")
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_internal_data() {
        let some_data = SomeData(Box::from(MockProvider()));

        assert_eq!(Some(String::from("Mocked data")), some_data.get_some_data())
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_ne_internal_data() {
        let some_data = SomeData(Box::from(MockProvider()));

        assert_ne!(Some(String::from("Not the expected data")), some_data.get_some_data())
    }
}
```

The result code can be seem in the rust playground, hope this help user to design their code.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=62348977502accfed55fa4600d149bcd